# Modulo operation notation

Tags: notation

I would like to write that some polynomial $p(x)$ is the sum of polynomial $d(x)$ and the remainder of division of polynomial $b(x)$ by polynomial $w(x)$:

$$p(x) = d(x) + b(x)\bmod w(x)$$

But from what I saw in books, this can mean something different which is:

$$p(x) = (d(x) + b(x))\bmod w(x)$$

So, what is a good way to write what I mean?

Comment: When in doubt, add brackets.

Comment: (b mod w) is a shorthand for the set {b+qw ; q polynomial}. Hence d+(b mod w)=(d+b) mod w since both are {d+b+qw ; q polynomial}.

Comment: @Didier: I think it's clear from context that the OP wants to discuss an operation which returns the remainder. But I agree that the use of $\text{mod}$ for this is an abuse of notation and should be replaced with something else.

Comment: I would write it exactly like you, but add brackets. So $p(x) = (d(x) + b(x)\bmod w(x))$ but $p(x)\not=d(x)+b(x)\mod w(x)$. Notice also, that the spacing is also different.

Comment: Write it as $\rm\ p = d + (b\ mod\ w)\ $ to avoid confusion with $\rm p = d + b\ (mod\ w)\:,\ $ or use $\rm\:(b\ rem\ w)\:.$

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not specific to polynomials, it also occurs for integers. In particular, every programming language has to deal with this question. For instance, just compare the following results (in Python, but you could choose C, Java, C++, etc.). Here % means mod.

```
7 + 7 % 5 
9

(7 + 7) % 5 
4

7 + (7 % 5) 
9
```

You conclude that 7 + 7 % 5 was interpreted as 7 + (7 % 5). The reason is that $C$-style languages use [precedence levels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations) to avoid ambiguity. In particular, multiplication, division and modulo have higher priority than addition.

That being said, Rule 8 of [The Elements of Programming Style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Elements_of_Programming_Style) states

> Parenthesize to avoid ambiguity

which confirms Zhen Li's and Bill Dubuque's comments to your question.